# Geometrical interpretation of complex exponential integral

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, area, geometric-measure-theory

Coefficients of Fourier series of a function $f$ are computed by multiplying $f(x)$ by the exponential term $e^{-inx}$, then by integrating $f(x)e^{-inx}$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and dividing by $2\pi$ (this is not the general case, let me keep the notation simple).

In this way we are "freezing" the index $n$, and the integral is able to compute $c_n$.

This is due to the fact that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ikx}dx=0$ for all $k\ne0$. I am able to solve this integral, but I would like to "see" it, as a kind of geometric proof.

So my question is: which is the geometrical meaning of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ikx}dx$?

Should I draw a three dimensional curve and then calculate the area of a surface? It is not obvious to me that this area should be equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{ix}$ is a vector of length 1 and argument $x$.

$e^{ix}dx$ is a vector of length $dx$ and argument $x$.

The sum of all these vectors is, intuitivelly speaking (or even rigorously speaking, if one is allowed to use non standard analisys), a closed polygon with infinitely many edges of lenght $dx$.

This is an example figure with $n=10$ edges:

[image]

$e^{ikx}dx$ is a closed "polygon" which makes $k$ turns around the origin.

In any case, the sum of all these vectors is null.